# Insert XPath Query into Database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, xpath, domdocument

I'm making a scraper in which the user can create templates in which he/she controls what is scraped, the Template editor will store the XPath Locations as I can use the XPath Alongside DOMDocument. the PHP Script I Currently Have for Storing the Queries Is:

```
<?php



    $mysql = new mysqli("*****" , "*****" , "*****" , "price_scraper");

    $prod_name = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $prod_price = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
    $prod_stock = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['stock']);
    $prod_desc = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
    $prod_image = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['image']);
    $prod_styles = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['styles']);
    $prod_offer_prices = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['offer_price']);
    $prod_man_ref = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['man_ref']);
    $prod_specs = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['specs']);
    $website_id = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['site_id']);


    $query = "INSERT INTO `scraper_templates` (`product_name` , `product_price` , `product_stock` , `product_description` , `product_image` , `product_styles` , `product_offer_prices` , `product_man_ref` , `product_specs` , `website_id`) VALUES ('$prod_name' , '$prod_price' , '$prod_stock' , '$prod_desc' , '$prod_image' , '$prod_styles' , '$prod_offer_prices' , '$prod_man_ref' , '$prod_specs' , '$website_id')";

    $q = $mysql->query($query);

    if($q){
        die("1");
    }else{
        die("0");
    }
?>
```

When I come to Insert the XPath Values into the Database the database all the Rows are empty. I thought escaping the string would solve the problem but thats not the case.

Comment: Is it empty as there is no new record inserted, or empty as values are blank but a new record inserted?. PS, use

Comment: Does your php die with exit code 0 or 1? @GabrielRodriguez: looks like something's missing at the end of your comment.

Comment: Dump the query and run it by hand against the database and see what happens. Try to fix it. If it doesn't help, post the actual query created here and we may be able to help you. Currently, it is too much of a guessing game because we don't see the actual query.